# Dataview Table.Rows.Count is returning 1 when there is no such rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

consider the code below:

```
DataView deletedLOV = new DataView(tbltmp, "prociLOV_Deleted=1", "prociLOV_ID",
                                   DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
DataView addedLOV = new DataView(tbltmp, "prociLOV_Id>1", "prociLOV_ID",
                                 DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
int deletedLOVcount=deletedLOV.Table.Rows.Count;
int addedLOVcount=addedLOV.Table.Rows.Count;
```

prociLOV_Deleted is set to 1 when a record is deleted.

But even when no records are deleted the deletedLOVcount return value 1. Also the same with addedLOVcount when there is no record with proci_ID>1 ,it too returns count as1

Answer (score 6):

The `DataView` references it's original DataTable via the `Table` property. But it does not share the same data. The `DataTable` contains the original data without the applied filter whereas the `DataView` contains only the records after the appplied filter.

You would get the correct count via [`DataView.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.count.aspx):

```
int deletedLOVcount = deletedLOV.Count;
```

MSDN:

> Gets the number of records in the DataView after RowFilter and
>   RowStateFilter have been applied.

Comment: but the deletedLOV's row filter is not working as expected..Rows are added as and when added to addedLOV filter

Comment: @user1869914: So what does `DataView.Count` return and what does `DataView.Table.Rows.Count` return and what would be correct for both?

Comment: ,but i need to get those filtered rows..Ny wy of getting those filtered rows from the datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Having a DataView with different filters on it and made simple test with a ContextMexuStrip that reflects by simply right click the amount of DataView.Count exactly by choosen filter. So I confirm this is the right pick that represents available rows in the View after a filter is applied to all available rows in the view.

example code:

```
DataGridView myDGV = new DataGridView();
... ( set up your dgv )
DataView myDV = new DataView();
... ( add handlers if you need )
DataTable myDT = new DataTable(myDV);
myDGV.BindSource = myDT;
```

By adding to a contextmenustrip myCMS.Item.Add(" available entries : " + myDV.Count() ); you have it reflected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).